# Vorticity of a velocity field in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, vector-fields, vortex

I'm currently working on a obtaining the vorticity of my velocity field $u_r, u_\theta, u_x$. I know that this is equal to the curl of the velocity field $\nabla \times u$:

$$\nabla \times u = \frac{1}{r} \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{e_r} & r\boldsymbol{e_\theta} & \boldsymbol{e_x} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
u_r & r u_\theta & u_x
\end{bmatrix} $$

Am I right in saying that this is the same as:

$$\nabla \times u = \frac{1}{r}\left[
\left(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial\theta} - \frac{\partial (r u_\theta)}{\partial x}\right)\boldsymbol{e_r} + \left(r\left(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial x}\right)\right)\boldsymbol{e_\theta} + \left(\frac{\partial(r u_\theta)}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta}\right)\boldsymbol{e_x}
\right]$$

I'm currently thinking that I'm interpreting the $r\boldsymbol{e_\theta}$ incorrectly and that the second term should actually have a $\frac{1}{r}$ and not a $r$ in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct curl in cylindrical coordinates is 
$$
\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial \theta}-
\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial x}\right)\mathbf{e_r}+ \left(\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial r}\right)\mathbf{e_\theta}+
\frac {1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial (r u_\theta)}{\partial r}-\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta}\right)\mathbf{e_x},
$$
as you can see in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates). Your only mistake was the sign of the term in the direction $\mathbf{e_\theta}$.